# How to add column in Pivot table with custom calculation or work with multiple sheets

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to work with Pivot table with some calculation from another sheet then its range. Can it possible to add column inside pivot able  or at end of pivot table with custom calculation.

```
Sheet 1 format

A B C D

Sheet 2 format

D E F C B

Sheet 3 format

D E F C B A
```

another option for this is How to make pivot table with different source of data in all sheet B is conman for everyone.I tried SQL query but it will not work until it will be in same format for all.

It will be helpful if you can provide some solution to the situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it in both ways:

- **Calculated Fields** in the Pivot Table: you can find a step by step guide at [this link](http://www.contextures.com/excel-pivot-table-calculated-field.html).
- **MySQL** query to a database:

  - create three tables, one for each sheet
  - make sure that you can link the tables to each other (a common ID or something similar)
  - if so, you can join the different tables in the same query and make your calculation

I would say that the easier solution is to create calculated fields.
A database will be much more powerful but it might be out of the scope of your needs.

**Edit after reading your file**

It seems that you need to compare the balance according to three data sources:

- *Sap Data* tab
- *Company Code ICR* tab
- *Trading Partner ICR* tab

Since you have in common the most of information, you might want to map all the data on the same page and then to do a PivotTable.

E.g. Add to **Snap Data** tab the information of **Company Code ICR**

- Choose a unique identifier for the same item in both sheets (Document No.)
- Choose the column you want to get
- Add a column to your original tab
- Use [VLOOKUP](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/VLOOKUP-function-0bbc8083-26fe-4963-8ab8-93a18ad188a1) function

If you need more details, leave a comment and I will include more elements to the answer

Comment: Thanks for options i tried to calculate column with macro but its bad luck for me it not worked. Also MYsql or SQl query way i tried and its very good and i want to use it but i am not sure. As file should not get to complex and heavy due to table. IF file size increase then normal it will be issue. Also I am not sure can i use macros to copy paste data in tables or not.

Comment: Can you attach your excel file and explain exactly which calculations you want to perform?

Comment: Did my answer reply to your question? If so, could you close the question?

Comment: Sorry.. I am not well so i didnt answer... As soon i get well i will attach sample for you

Comment: Ok, don't worry! You can upload it somewhere and then just put the link and I will look into it. Get well soon

Comment: Hi link is as below:-
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BxOkR3hAlAs9TnFaUEZBMHFodDA/view?usp=sharing   ..... Also column in red are conman for pivot table...

Comment: Please see I attached link above

Comment: The answer edited is already taking in consideration your file :)

Comment: sorry i not seen that... that option can create file heavy.. there are approx. 250K rows in excel and formulas can create it more size in future. i like SQl option but how to use it in 3 sheets with no conman feild...

Comment: If it is about sql, each sheet would be a table and then you can make a query where you join the three tables. Can you create three tables with all the data? I will help you to write a query for that purpose

Comment: Sure.. Please help how should I use it